# Make shell output HTML ready

Tags: html, bash, shell, tr

I work with a system wherein we can use a shell script to produce output for a web interface. It works pretty well, but in the case of an issue today, I need to be able to insert a break tag where a newline stop would normally go. My script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
users=`decl . -read /Groups/admin | grep GroupMembers | tr ' ' '\n'`
echo "<result>"$users"</result>"
```

I'm looking for a way for the `\n` to be a `<br />`, which does not work by just replacing it in the command. The script works, meaning it effectively grabs the data and displays it in our web interface, but the users are all on one line, which is not the desired result.

Answer (score 3):

`tr` only replaces a single character with a single character (or with nothing, if using `-d`). To replace a single character with multiple characters, you need to use something else.

The option that's most similar to your current code is to use `sed` instead of `tr`:

```
#!/bin/bash
users=`decl . -read /Groups/admin | grep GroupMembers | sed 's# #<br />#g'`
echo "<result>"$users"</result>"
```

Comment: Thank's for this as well. I haven't tried it yet, but if it works, it seems like a "more correct" way.

Comment: From the description, it sounds like `sed 's#$#<br />#'` would be more apropriate.

Comment: Good use of `#` to avoid having to escape the `/`.

Comment: @glennjackman: You may be right. To me, the OP sounded confident that his current script was correct aside from its producing `\n` rather than `<br />`, so I gave a script that made only that one change; but judging from his reply to sampson-chen's answer, it seems that this was not actually the change he needed.

Answer (score 1):

Include `$users` into the quotes for your `echo` command. i.e. update your script to:

```
#!/bin/bash
users=`decl . -read /Groups/admin | grep GroupMembers | tr ' ' '\n'`
echo "<result>$users</result>"
```

And that should solve the "*users are all on one line*" problem

Comment: But it doesn't convert the newlines to HTML `<br>`.

Comment: No, but it produces the desired result.

Comment: @CarltonBrumbelow glad you got what you are looking for =)